# How can I select a random value from a two-dimensional array?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a program that selects a random value from a two-dimensional array and assigns the values to 2 variables.

There are 2 values in the array, "song" and "artist". I want it to choose a random song and assign the value "song" and "artist" to 2 separate variables.
For Example, If the song was "song1" and the artist for that song was "artist1" I would want it to assign a variable called chosensong to "song1" and chosenartist to "artist1".

I've tried to use a Dim (Dim testing) but I do not know how to use it in a two-dimensional array.

```
Dim songart(,) As String = {{"song1", "artist1"},{"song2","artist2"}}

Dim testing(New Random().Next(0, testing.Length - 1))
```

Comment: What if you also want to know the duration of the song or the year? The genre? Do you know how to build a class? Anyway, see [Array.GetUpperBound](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound). Declare your random generator as a Field: `private rndSong As Random = New Random()`. Then you can have (somewhere): `Dim nextSong = rndSong.Next(songart.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)` and `Dim Song as String = songart(nextSong, 0) Dim Artist as string = songart(nextSong, 1)`. Unless this is a specific assignment, see how you can build a class with different properties (and methods).

Comment: I only want the program to have the Song Name and the Artist of the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Public Class FormRandom
        Private Shared Rdm As New Random


        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim songart(,) As String = {{"song1", "artist1"}, {"song2", "artist2"}, {"song3", "artist3"}, {"song4", "artist4"}}

            Dim RndNo As Integer = Rdm.Next(0, (songart.GetLength(0)))

            Dim SoundName As String = songart(RndNo, 0)
            Dim ArtistName As String = songart(RndNo, 1)

            TextBox1.Text = SoundName
            TextBox2.Text = ArtistName
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Duh, i didnt consider that length would return the length of both dimensions. Will update code

Comment: `songart.GetLength(0)-1`returns 3 (i did add more elements)

Comment: Nor did I, I tested the code and it's only outputting song1 and artist1.

Comment: Apologies, I seem to have just gotten the same value after testing about 5 times? What are the chances! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: right. maybe i am misunderstanding the requirement? you can drop the -1 even or it would never return the last dimension

Comment: updated code. if its not what you want ill delete it

Comment: @Jimi Got ya. (I dont much use multi dimensional arrays)

Comment: A suggestion.  Change  Dim Rdm As New Random  to  Private shared Rdm As New Random.  One instance of the random class is almost always the best policy.

Comment: I had to change a few things but it now works fully. Thanks to everyone for the help